# How do I display one (featured) post from Wordpress on my static html website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We have a Wordpress News Blog on our website (http://www.litepanels.com/news/) that is separate from the rest of the static html website.  I just want to take the latest story (the featured post) and display it on our home page.  The Blog and our website are on the same server.  I found I can grab post titles like this:

```
<?php
require('../news/wp-blog-header.php');
 ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php       the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php endwhile;?>
```

but I do not know PHP well, how do I grab just the featured post (which has a title, image and text as you can see in the link above)

I am testing it here: http://www.litepanels.com/newwebsite/blog_test2.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230021/multiple-specific-post-in-wordpress, had the same problem might help you.

Comment: @tomexsans Sure you linked to the page you intended? Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

If that works for you, it means you've got all you need except for some way to display your information. For this, Wordpress provides some template tags that can be used within the while loop. [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) is the one you need. [Others can be found in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)

Comment: thanks if you look at my test link above I am starting to get it.  I can fix the quick CSS I did but I did not understand how to cut off the rest of the content with a read more> type of link?

Comment: It should be done automatically if your content has a <!--more--> in it.